# Problems with canvas buttons in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i have buttons for my game that include : Main Menu button , Restart button and Play button. Everything works fine, but occasionally one of the button's text doesn't load , one of them doesn't work. I'm not sure how to fix this, because it happens randomly and not every time.

The code for the buttons :

```
GameObject[] pauseObjects;
void Start()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    pauseObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ShowOnPause");
    hidePaused();
}


public void showPaused()
{
    foreach (GameObject g in pauseObjects)
    {
        g.SetActive(true);
    }
}


public void hidePaused()
{
    foreach (GameObject g in pauseObjects)
    {
        g.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public void LoadLevel(string level)
{
    Application.LoadLevel(level);
}

public void pauseControl()
{
    if (Time.timeScale == 1)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        showPaused();
    }
    else if (Time.timeScale == 0)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        hidePaused();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I need a little bit of clarification. Randomly, one of your three buttons stops working, and has no text?
If so, can you show us the code that sets the buttons text and activates/deactivates the button?
The above code doesn't really help us, unless your buttons are all in "pauseObjects"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your UI is setup is not right. If you have to loop through everything during pause, you are doing it wrong. I have answered a similar question before and will just copy and paste this here.

Use different Canvas to **separate** your UI and group them depending on when they are displayed. Then you can toggle the whole Canvas **on**/**off**. Your [post][1] before this post shows that you are using image as button and you have a different script attached to two images you are using as buttons. Use **Buttons** for **buttons** and **image** for **non-clickable** objects. Simple as that. So change those images to buttons.

You don't need the GameOver scene. A GameOverCanvas is fine.
The GameObjects in bold are the **parent** Objects(Canvas). The ones under that starts with '**-**' are the **child** GameObjects.

**Step 1:**

Create `Canvas` and name it **MainMenuCanvas** (First UI to display when game Loads).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-playButton;
-settingsButton;
-exitGameButton;
```

Attach the [MainMenuCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/tw1kKKVG) to the **MainMenuCanvas** Object.

**Step 2:**

Create a `Canvas` and name it **GameCanvas** (Displayed during game).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-pauseButton
-jumpButton
```

Attach the [GameCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/C3WSzMQq) to the **GameCanvas** Object.

**Step 3:**

Create a `Canvas` and name it **PauseCanvas** (Displayed when pause button is clicked).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-resumeButton;
-backToMainMenuButton;
-settingsButton;
-exitGameButton;
```

Attach the [PauseCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/czSQtcCi) to the **PauseCanvas** Object.

**Step 4:**

Create a `Canvas` and name it **SettingsCanvas** (Displayed when settings button is clicked).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-backButton;
```

Attach the [SettingsCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/mi05Jnmk) to the **SettingsCanvas** Object.

**Step 5:**

Create a `Canvas` and name it **GameOverCanvas** (Displayed when Game is Over or player is killed).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-playAgainButton;
-backToMainMenuButton;
-exitGameButton;
```

Attach the [GameOverCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/jsPzNA17) to the **GameOverCanvas** Object.

**Step 6:**

In the **Game** scene, make sure that only **GameCanvas** is enabled. The rest of the canvas should be manually **disabled**.

**Step 7:**

In the **Menu** scene, make sure that only **MainMenuCanvas** is enabled. The rest of the canvas should be manually **disabled**.

Once you get this setup correctly, the UI code templates I provided should work. No more UI **overlapping** or text **disappearing**. You can easily add or remove features.

Your UI setup should look like the image below.

[image]

Comment: Everything works perfectly fine ! Thanks for putting in this much effort and helping me out. You're a legend.