# Making volume slider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider, 2d

Game starts, the music begins to play, but it's too annoying and want to mute or just make it quieter. Like games, there's setting menu, which I thought it would be good to be in next scene, and there I want to put slider.
But I got errors.

Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Music : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }

    public AudioClip[] soundtrack;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (!GetComponent<AudioSource>().playOnAwake)
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = soundtrack[Random.Range(0, soundtrack.Length)];
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
    }

// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying)
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = soundtrack[Random.Range(0, soundtrack.Length)];
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking the-same question twice is not a good idea. **you could change volume of music in next scene** Can you explain that?

Comment: I want that when game starts you go to next scene and change volume  with  slider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volume slider in Unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772662/volume-slider-in-unity)

Comment: Where is your code? Where is the sound playing code you have ?

Comment: Wait a second I will sent the code.

Comment: Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `AudioSource.volume` to change the volume. When you create a `Slider`, you can get the `value` of the slider with `Slider.value`. So, take `Slider.value` and assign it to `AudioSource.volume`.

To create s Slider, go to **GameObject**->**UI**->**Slider**. Make sure that `Min Value` is **0** and `Max Value` is **1**. Also make sure that `Whole Numbers` check box is NOT checked. Drag the `Slider` to the volume `Slider` slot in this script from the Editor.

**Note**:

If you are going to use a component more than once, cache it to a global variable instead of doing  `GetComponent<AudioSource>()` multiple times or using it in the `Update()` function.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Music : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] soundtrack;
    public Slider volumeSlider;

    AudioSource audioSource;


    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        if (!audioSource.playOnAwake)
        {
            audioSource.clip = soundtrack[Random.Range(0, soundtrack.Length)];
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            audioSource.clip = soundtrack[Random.Range(0, soundtrack.Length)];
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register Slider Events
        volumeSlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { changeVolume(volumeSlider.value); });
    }

    //Called when Slider is moved
    void changeVolume(float sliderValue)
    {
        audioSource.volume = sliderValue;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register Slider Events
        volumeSlider.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

You can learn more about Unity's UI [here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

Comment: This works. But when I put this in another scene, the first and other scenes don't react. Could you show me how to do that ?

Comment: @OneARMINAS You really need to lean how to ask a question. What doesn't work? What happens?  All this does is to change the sound volume with a slider.

Comment: I have two scenes.  I put slider in next scene. When I launched game (first scene ) music isn't playing.  Could you help me ?

Comment: @OneARMINAS Still dont understand. Where do you want the music to play? First or the Second scene? When do you load the second scene? You said the music is not playing....When is it suppose to start playing? First or the second scene?

Comment: I start a game. Music isn't playing, when I go to settings menu music appears

Comment: I want that when you launch game you are hearing music,  if it's too loud you go to next scene and make quieter.

Comment: @OneARMINAS I really don't think I can help anymore in this question. My solution can change the volume with the slider. You lack the **basic** knowledge to apply it to whatever you are doing. Follow the link I gave you in your first question I answered and complete a simple Unity tutorial project to be able to understand basic stuff. Even when anyone else manage to help you, you still wont be able to apply their solution because you don't know the basics. Finally, you don't need to load a new scene just to change the volume.

Comment: @OneARMINAS You create the menu canvas and enable/disable it when ever you need it. Here is a complete menu tutorial for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37263453/3785314 . You don't load new scene for that! Here is a unity tutorial. http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials Please do them. I ask you to so that you can easily make your game and will only ask questions when you really need help. You wont regret doing it.