# Canvas to Canvas (MainMenu to Options) Same Scene Unity

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine

I want my `OptionButton` from `MainMenu` to Hide the `MainMenuCanvas` so I can use the `OptionCanvas`, is it Possible?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Director : MonoBehaviour {
    private GameObject mainMenu, options;

    void Awake (){
       mainMenu = GameObject.Find ("MainMenuCanvas");
        options = GameObject.Find ("OptionCanvas");
        }
    void Start () {
        mainMenu.SetActive (true);
        options.SetActive (false);
    }
    void Update () {
      //should i put If.else here?
     /* like 
         if (button.clicked){
             mainMenu.SetActive (false);
             options.SetActive (true);*/
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible. Though I'd recommend using Canvas.enabled(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) variable for consistency.

Just create a function in a script to handle the click. f.e.

```
void onOptionsClick(){
if(mainMenuCanvas.enabled){
    mainMenuCanvas = false;
    optionCanvas = true;
 }  
 else{
    mainMenuCanvas = true;
    optionCanvas = false;
 }
}
```

This function should do what you want. Then you simply select the button and choose this function as a onClick() of that button in the Inspector.

Let me know if that works as I cannot test it atm!

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to register your `OptionButton`  event to a function. When that `Button` is clicked, the registered function will be called. `Button.onClick.AddListener` is used to register the `Button` event. `Button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners` is used to un-register the `Button` event.

```
private GameObject mainMenu, options;
public Button OptionButton;

void Awake()
{
    mainMenu = GameObject.Find("MainMenuCanvas");
    options = GameObject.Find("OptionCanvas");
}

void Start()
{
    mainMenu.SetActive(true);
    options.SetActive(false);
}

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Event
    OptionButton.onClick.AddListener(() => OptionButtonCallBack());

}

//Will be called when OptionButton is clicked
private void OptionButtonCallBack()
{
    mainMenu.SetActive(false);
    options.SetActive(true);
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Button Event
    OptionButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

You can find complete step to setup your UI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37263453/3785314).